# Replacing empty values in a DataFrame with value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, np.nan, 0],
                    [5, 4, 2, np.nan],
                    [7, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                    [9, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                    columns=list('ABCD'))
```

which returns this:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  NaN  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  NaN
2  7  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  9  3.0  NaN  4.0
```

I'd like that if a np.nan is found, that the value is replaced by a value in the A column. So that would mean the result to be this:

```
   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

I've tried multiple things, but I could not get anything to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is necessary double transpose:

```
cols = ['B','C', 'D']
df[cols] = df[cols].T.fillna(df['A']).T
print(df)
   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

because:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df['A'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

> NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and broadcasting column `A`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.isnull(), df['A'].values[:, None], df), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     A    B    C    D
0  3.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5.0  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7.0  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9.0  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

Thank you @pir for another solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.isnull(), df[['A']], df), 
                  index=df.index, 
                  columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Amazing that such a seemingly simple task requires such gymnastics. +1

Comment: for `np.where`: `np.where(df.isna(), df[['A']], df)`

Comment: Cheers for the answer, @jezrael. Both your solutions work, but the first one is still running as I type this, trying to complete this on my full dataset. The second solution however is very quick.

Comment: @user498537 - Yes, in large DataFrames second is faster.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, `fillna` doesn't allow for broadcasting a series across columns while aligning the indices.

#### `pandas.DataFrame.mask`

This functions exactly like what we'd want `fillna` to do.  Finds the the nulls, fills it in with `df.A` along `axis=0`

```
df.mask(df.isna(), df.A, axis=0)

   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` using a dictionary

However, you can pass a dictionary to `fillna` that tells it what to do for each column.

```
df.fillna({k: df.A for k in df})

   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

DO `fillna` with `reindex`

```
df.fillna(df[['A']].reindex(columns=df.columns).ffill(1))
Out[20]: 
   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

Or `combine_first`

```
df.combine_first(df.fillna(0).add(df.A,0))
Out[35]: 
   A    B    C    D
0  3  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  5  4.0  2.0  5.0
2  7  7.0  7.0  5.0
3  9  3.0  9.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# for each column...
for col in df.columns:
    # I select the np.nan and I replace then with the value of A
    df.loc[df[col].isnull(), col] = df["A"]
```